# Most memory-efficient way to read & store list of strings in C

Tags: c, c-strings, memory-optimization

I'd like to know what's the most memory efficient way to read & store a list of strings in C.

Each string may have a different length, so pre-allocating a big 2D array would be wasteful.
I also want to avoid a separate malloc for each string, as there may be many strings.

The strings will be read from a large buffer into this list data-structure I'm asking about.

Is it possible to store all strings separately with a single allocation of exactly the right size?

One idea I have is to store them contiguously in a buffer, then have a char * array pointing to the different parts in the buffer, which will have '\0's in it to delimit. I'm hoping there's a better way though.

```
struct list {
  char *index[32];
  char buf[];
};
```

The data-structure and strings will be strictly read-only.

Comment: how about a link-list of contiguous buffers - so you dont have to expensively reallocate

Comment: @amdixon he does not want to `malloc` for each string.

Comment: @amdixon yea the problem is I'd like to be able to use a single free() for the whole thing, if possible.

Comment: If you don't ever intend to change the length of any of the strings then your idea is remarkably elegant.

Comment: The solution largely depends if the stored list of strings is **static** and read-only at the end, or if you would like to be able to add/remove/update strings. So which operations shall be available after creating the string list?

Comment: @Flovdi they are read-only.

Comment: @cloudhead Storing all the strings in one is ok if you store their number in the beginning or, for instance, you may add some additional '\0' to the end. You need some additional information to determine then to stop reading strings.

Comment: @Bathsheba only issue is the fixed sized index..

Comment: Although having a big buffer with '\0' separator works for constant strings and is used in many (specially old) c programs, you have to keep the buffer consistent and it can be very hard if you need to change the size of any string. I believe you'd better be served with an alternative memory allocator that could reserve memory chunks from OS an serve it in a granular basis to your application.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mildly efficient format, assuming you know the length of all the strings in advance:

```
|| total size |  string 1 | string 2 | ........ | string N | len(string N) | ... | len(string 2) | len(string 1) ||
```

You can store the lengths either in fixed-width integers or in variable-width integers, but the point is that you can jump to the end and scan all the *lengths* relatively efficiently, and from the length sum you can compute the offset of the string. You know when you reached the last string when there is no remaining space.

Comment: Interesting, but how does this look in C? I still would like to be able to have working char *'s for the strings, not a completely opaque buffer.

Comment: You could store consecutive NUL-delimited strings, so you could just take the offset (buffer[offset]) and pass that into a funcion expecting a char*

Comment: @cloudhead: As Aktau says, it's up to you whether you want to include a null terminator. That's certainly an option. And computing the offset of the kth string is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your single buffer and store them contiguously, expanding the buffer as needed by using `realloc()`. But then you would need a second array to store string positions and maybe `realloc()` it as well, so I might simply create a dynamically allocated array and `malloc()` each string separately.

Answer (score 0):

**Find the number and total-length of all strings:**

```
int num = 0;
int len = 0;
char* string = GetNextString(input);
while (string)
{
    num += 1;
    len += strlen(string);
    string = GetNextString(input);
}
Rewind(input);
```

**Then, allocate the following two buffers:**

```
int*  indexes = malloc(num*sizeof(int));
char* strings = malloc((num+len)*sizeof(char));
```

**Finally, fill these two buffers:**

```
int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    indexes[i] = index;
    string = GetNextString(input);
    strcpy(strings+index,string);
    index += strlen(string)+1;
}
```

After that, you can simply use `strings[indexes[i]]` in order to access the ith string.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient and memory efficient way is a two pass solution. In the first pass you calculate the total size for all strings, then you allocate the total memory block. In the second pass you read all strings using large buffers.

You can create a pointer array for the strings and calculate the difference between the pointers to get the string sizes. This way you save the null byte as end marker.

Here a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct StringMap
{
    char *data;
    char **ptr;
    long cPos;
};


void initStringMap(StringMap *stringMap, long numberOfStrings, long totalCharacters)
{
    stringMap->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(totalCharacters+1));
    stringMap->ptr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(numberOfStrings+2));
    memset(stringMap->ptr, 0, sizeof(char*)*(numberOfStrings+1));
    stringMap->ptr[0] = stringMap->data;
    stringMap->ptr[1] = stringMap->data;
    stringMap->cPos = 0;
}


void extendString(StringMap *stringMap, char *str, size_t size)
{
    memcpy(stringMap->ptr[stringMap->cPos+1], str, size);
    stringMap->ptr[stringMap->cPos+1] += size;
}


void endString(StringMap *stringMap)
{
    stringMap->cPos++;
    stringMap->ptr[stringMap->cPos+1] = stringMap->ptr[stringMap->cPos];
}


long numberOfStringsInStringMap(StringMap *stringMap)
{
    return stringMap->cPos;
}


size_t stringSizeInStringMap(StringMap *stringMap, long index)
{
    return stringMap->ptr[index+1] - stringMap->ptr[index];
}


char* stringinStringMap(StringMap *stringMap, long index)
{
    return stringMap->ptr[index];
}


void freeStringMap(StringMap *stringMap)
{
    free(stringMap->data);
    free(stringMap->ptr);
}


int main()
{
    // The interesting values
    long numberOfStrings = 0;
    long totalCharacters = 0;

    // Scan the input for required information
    FILE *fd = fopen("/path/to/large/textfile.txt", "r");
    int bufferSize = 4096;
    char *readBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferSize);
    int currentStringLength = 0;
    ssize_t readBytes;
    while ((readBytes = fread(readBuffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, fd))>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; ++i) {
            const char c = readBuffer[i];
            if (c != '\n') {
                ++currentStringLength;
            } else {
                ++numberOfStrings;
                totalCharacters += currentStringLength;
                currentStringLength = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the found results
    printf("Found %ld strings with total of %ld bytes\n", numberOfStrings, totalCharacters);

    // Allocate the memory for the resource
    StringMap stringMap;
    initStringMap(&stringMap, numberOfStrings, totalCharacters);

    // read all strings
    rewind(fd);
    while ((readBytes = fread(readBuffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, fd))>0) {
        char *stringStart = readBuffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; ++i) {
            const char c = readBuffer[i];
            if (c == '\n') {
                extendString(&stringMap, stringStart, &readBuffer[i]-stringStart);
                endString(&stringMap);
                stringStart = &readBuffer[i+1];
            }
        }
        if (stringStart < &readBuffer[readBytes]) {
            extendString(&stringMap, stringStart, &readBuffer[readBytes]-stringStart);
        }
    }
    endString(&stringMap);
    fclose(fd);

    // Ok read the list
    numberOfStrings = numberOfStringsInStringMap(&stringMap);
    printf("Number of strings in map: %ld\n", numberOfStrings);
    for (long i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; ++i) {
        size_t stringSize = stringSizeInStringMap(&stringMap, i);
        char *buffer = (char*)malloc(stringSize+1);
        memcpy(buffer, stringinStringMap(&stringMap, i), stringSize);
        buffer[stringSize-1] = '\0';
        printf("string %05ld size=%8ld : %s\n", i, stringSize, buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }

    // free the resource
    freeStringMap(&stringMap);
}
```

This example reads a very large text file, splits it into lines and creates an array with a string per line. It only needs two `malloc` calls. One for the pointer array and one for the sting block.

Answer (score 0):

If it's strictly read-only as you've described, you can store the entire list of strings and their offsets in a single chunk of memory and read the whole thing with a single read.

The first `sizeof(long) bytes` stores the number of strings, `n`. The next `n` longs store the offsets into each string from the start of the `string buffer` which starts at position (n+1)*sizeof(long). You don't have to store the trailing zero for each string, but if you do, you can access each string with &str_buffer[offset[i]]. If you don't store the trailing '\0' then you would have to copy into a temporary buffer and append it yourself.